# Read file into array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, arrays, file

I have a file of words/phrases separated by newlines.  I need to get the file and read each word/phrase into the array.  I have this so far:

```
    NSFileHandle *wordsFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:[[NSBundle     mainBundle] pathForResource:@"WordList"
                                                                                                           ofType:nil]];
    NSData *words = [wordsFile readDataToEndOfFile];
    [wordsFile closeFile];
    [wordsFile release];
```

But I'm not sure if that's right, and if so, where to go from there.

Also, teabot's answer of

NSString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet

works great, but it's 10.5 only.  **How would this behavior be replicated for 10.4?**

Answer (score 11):

Here is an approach that should work - I'll leave out an actual code example as the implementation should be fairly straightforward given following:

Construct an NSString from your file with:

```
NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error
```

Split the string into an array of NSStrings using the following:

```
NSString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet
```

You should end up with an NSArray of NSStrings with each string containing one of the lines in your file.

Comment: Don't forget to filter out empty strings caused by blank lines, including the one that UNIX editors (such as vi) will leave at the end of the file.

Comment: That works great, but those last two are 10.5 only- what would replace them if I want compatibility on 10.4?

Comment: Good call re: 10.4.x - I would advise you to revise the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 11):

Just for completeness (and because I am bored) here's a complete example bassed on teabot's post:

```
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                            pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"txt"]];

    NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
    NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

Comment: stringWithContentsOfFile:pathForResource:ofType deprecated

"Use stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error: or stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error: instead."